# differentiation operator in second power.

Tags: calculus

Could that be that after developing mathematical expression to be integrated later on you end up having **dx squared**. As to my knowledge so far all integration formulas assume dx to be at power one. Where is my mistake if I have come up with expression
$R^2 \sin t \cos t dt^2$ under integration? Does that mean I need to do double integration?

To rephrase, my question is how do you integrate expression containing infinitesimal dx in second power (dt2) while all integration formulas assume it to be at power one?

Comment: More detail is needed.  We can't tell if you've made a mistake coming up with that expression if we can't see what steps you took to get there.

Comment: How are we supposed to identify the mistake in your work if you don't tell us your work?

Comment: Short answer is no, any squares of these infinitesimals $dx$, etc. are intrinsically zero terms.  A slightly longer answer is that these "infinitesimals" are anti-commutative, e.g. $dx \; dy = - dy \; dx$ and $dx \; dx = 0$.

Comment: In general, unless one is a differential geometer (which I'm not so I follow this too), it's better to leave $dx$ as notation, knowing that it follows certain rules (like when you change variables) and calculate accordingly.

Comment: this is a sample of the perils in the land of the non-standard calculus